# React Native round corner looks weired

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have set view border to give `TextInput` some corners. I used native `View` & `TextInput`.

```
           <View
                style={{
                  borderColor: 'red',
                  borderRadius: 25,
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  height: 50
                }}
              >
                <TextInput
                  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                  placeholder="Name"
                />
              </View>
```

How does this look in android (both in emulator (768*1280) & Motorola c2 mobile)

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: Please include the name and version of the OS/emulator the screenshot is from. Also does it look the same on all OSes/emulators?

Comment: It looks same in real device & emulator. This screenshot is from emulator.

Comment: Also what version of `react-native` are you using?

Comment: "react-native": "0.55.4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known React Native issue [Jagged rendering of round borders on Android #17311](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17311) and has a fix that will be in the `0.56` release. From [the last comment on that issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17267#issuecomment-396434109):

> This fix is now part of the latest release candidate: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.56.0-rc
>
> The schedule is meant to provide a reasonably stable release every month or so, but there's nothing preventing anyone from using React Native from master. In the future, you can take advantage of any fixes-in-master-but-not-yet-in-a-release by using React Native from master or pinning your react-native package to the commit that introduced the fix.

Comment: I scare of upgrading version, is this safe to upgrade?

Comment: I've never done one but I guess it depends on what else is in this release. Since you require the fix, I suggest trying the upgrade and rolling back if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll try upgrading project.